# AngularJS - slash in URL overrides for resources

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have RESTful Angular resource which I would like to extend with some custom actions.  As a first step, I take out **url** so I can override it in some of those actions:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myAwsomeApp').factory('Consignment', function ($resource) {
  return  $resource('/:url/:id', { id: '@id', url: "api/things" });
});
```

Taking out the URL immediately breaks stuff, my URLs are now loose the slash:

```
http://localhost:3000/api%2Fthings
```

The slash is replace with %2F.  Is there is a way to avoid such problems?

PS: I am using Angular 1.0.6